# OpenWhisper System Signal Build Maven Build error

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

Hi I am trying to build [Signal Server](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Server) by OpenWhisperSystems. Everytime I issue

> mvn clean install

I get following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TextSecureServer: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.whispersystems.textsecure:TextSecureServer:jar:1.22: Failed to collect dependencies at org.whispersystems:websocket-resources:jar:0.4.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.whispersystems:websocket-resources:jar:0.4.1: Failure to find org.whispersystems:parent:pom:0.4.1 in https:raw.github.com/whispersystems/maven/master/gcm-server/releases/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MVN Repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

I am stuck here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As khmarbaise said the problem is the lack of availability for the dependency.

The best option for this is to clone the github repository for this project and build it locally: [Github Repository](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/WebSocket-Resources)

A workaround for this is to download the jar from the maven repository:

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.whispersystems/websocket-resources/0.4.1/)

and manually add it using the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=!!![add file path here]!!! -DgroupId=org.whispersystems -DartifactId=websocket-resources -Dversion=0.4.1 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

[Maven documentation reference](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whispersystems/maven/master/gcm-server/releases/

you will get an error which means there are no dependencies available at all..This is the issue...